# Python equivalent of =REPLACE either before or after reading CSV (removing spaces)

Tags: python, csv, parsing, replace

I have a simple program that currently reads a CSV file and prints the two columns I want.

But, I need a way to replace the `' '` with `''` so I can use the info in `row[38]` to append to a URL string.

Is it best to tell Python 'csv' function not to read any `' '` or somehow tell it only to print characters that are not `' '`?

My code is

```
import csv
with open('/root/Downloads/Drivers.csv', newline='', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    # CHECK THE ENCODING! - 'Chardet' if needed.
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], row[38])
```

Comment: why not `row[38].replace(' ','')`

Comment: Perfect! - I also just realised ignoring ' ' would on read would be bad as it's the newline indicator :)